# Deserialize dynamic/variable Inner XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have an XML configuration file:

```
<Config>
   <FixedElement1/>
   <FixedElement2/>
   <UserDefinedElement>
      <UnknownUserElement1/>
      <UnknownUserElement2/>
   </UserDefinedElement>
</Config>
```

I have serialization and deserialization working on the fixed elements. But I want to read user defined elements that are not known.

How can I do it?

I am trying to do this way but it returns me nothing
[XmlText]
public String UserDefinedElement{ get; set; }

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in the app.config by defining custom config sections which can be deserialised into an object collection. A good guide on achieving this can be found here: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/11/13/app-config-and-custom-configuration-sections.aspx

If you are wishing to use your custom config you will still need to specify the object which has been serialized. If you are implementing ISerializable then you can use reflection to determine the object type and create at run-time.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use web.config. Basically this is a plug-in system configuration file. This file contains all the settings for plug-ins which are required by the system. But then there might be different settings for each plug-in. Therefore, I want to define it in separate xml instead of web.config.

Comment: Although I am reading the plugin configuration file path from web.config

Comment: Are you saying you want to deserialize a <UserDefinedElement> into a dynamic user defined object at runtime? Without any prior knowledge/implementation of that class?